# how to use Unordered HTML List in excel vba code?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have been trying to send a email via excel and use html in the message body but it seems excel does not reconize de

<\li>. I have the microsoft html Oject library added.

```
Sub send()
 Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "dupma4"
       '.CC = "Patrick.Blouin@mern.gouv.qc.ca;Veronic.Cinq-Mars@mern.gouv.qc.ca"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Ajouts d'adresse | [" & mun & " " & ville & "] | [" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "]"
        .HTMLBody = "Bonjour," & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                    & "<ul>" & "<li> & message1 & "</li>" & "<li>" & message2 _ 
                     & "</li>" & "</ul>"
        '.Send

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an ending quotation mark (") for your first `li`.  So it should be as follows...

```
.HTMLBody = "Bonjour," & "<br>" & "<br>" _
            & "<ul>" & "<li>" & message1 & "</li>" & "<li>" & message2 _
             & "</li>" & "</ul>"
```

Comment: Thank you what a flagrant fault! my bad!